# Ifelse statement in R: One value cannot equal another

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe with two columns: `df$user` and `df$type`. The users are a list of different user names and the type category has two values: `'high_user'` and `'small_user'`

I want to create some code so that one user cannot be both types. For example if the `user` is `high_user` he cannot also be a `small_user`.

```
head(df$user)

[1] RompnStomp       Vladiman         Celticdreamer54  Crimea is Russia shrek1978third   annietattooface 

head(df$type)

"high_user" "high_user" "small_user" "high_user" "high_user" "small_user"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to SO. please provide a minimal reproducible example with example data and the expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you choose the type, if one user has two or more types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to assign the first value of `User` to all the values of it's `type`.

```
df$new_type <- df$type[match(df$User, unique(df$User))]
df

#  User       type   new_type
#1    a  high_user  high_user
#2    b  high_user  high_user
#3    a small_user  high_user
#4    c small_user small_user
#5    c  high_user small_user
```

---

This can also be done using grouped operations.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(User) %>% mutate(new_type = first(type))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(User = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'), 
      type = c('high_user', 'high_user', 'small_user', 'small_user', 'high_user'))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
df$new_type <- with(df, ave(type, User, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(User = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'), 
      type = c('high_user', 'high_user', 'small_user', 'small_user', 'high_user'))
```